# Serial Version Mismatch in PySpark HiveConext Collect() function in yarn-client

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently running into issues while querying Hive tables using the "yarn-client" master like below.

This code works fine if I use master="local"

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("My App")
sc=SparkContext(master="yarn-client")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
test = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'x'").collect()
```

in this case I get the following error and cause.

```
17/06/26 12:22:43 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/hellospark_2_.py", line 31, in <module>
    test = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'x'").collect()
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 280, in collect
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4259705229845269663, local class serialVersionUID = 3305180847846277455
```

After some testing I've found that this error only occurs while using .collect(), and only when querying rows from a Hive dataframe. Querying names, table lists, or table descriptions works fine.

From what I saw online, it could potentially be caused by a Spark, Scala, or Hadoop version mismatch. In my testing I've found that Spark is the same when running in local or yarn-client (version 1.6.1). I have also looked at the dataframe.py file locally and remotely but that appears to be the same in both cases.

I would appreciate any insight or help with the question!

Thanks for your time.